RNA Secondary Structure Prediction Algorithm
I am currently working on my Final Project for the Biomed Datamining class, where the main goal is to 'Predict RNA Secondary Structure'.
I am given a set of RNA sequences in FASTA format and am tasked with writing an algorithm to predict their secondary structures. However, I am restricted from using any external software (already available online) or machine learning libraries (like scikit-learn).
As I am not a Biomed major, I am kind stuck on this project rn. What are some of the simplest algorithms I could implement for this prediction task? Where can I find more information about these algorithms?
Thank you

This is an easy question but I am not sure this is the right site for it.

This question would be a better fit for SE Bionformatics. However it is not clear whether your task is to write (devise might be a better word) an algorithm or write a program. If it’s an algorithm, we can’t help you as it would be doing your homework for you.

In addition, the length of the sequence is very relevant. 10nt is easy, 1000 is not.
